# Apache Rewrite Directory With Exceptions

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to setup a rewrite that will get any pages that are in the news folder (with the exception of index.shtml and template.shtml (where template.shtml will have a get variable news in it).  All other pages should rewrite to template.shtml?news=(same name as news/name).

What I have so far is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/((index|template).shtml)?$
RewriteRule ^news/(.*) /news/template.shtml?news=$1
```

This seems to exclude the main /news/, but not template.shtml and the rewrite seems to loop.

How can I resolve this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well -- this one works just fine for me:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/(index|template)\.shtml$
RewriteRule ^news/(.+)$ /news/template.shtml?news=$1 [L,QSA]
```

1. This rule will ignore requests to `/news/index.shtml` and `/news/template.shtml`.
2. It will also do nothing when requesting just `/news/` (as I have changed `.*` to `.+` to be on a safer side).
3. Anything else will be rewritten to `/news/template.shtml?news=whatever`
4. I've also added the `QSA` flag to preserve any existing query string (useful for keeping referral data, e.g. `/news/hello-pink-kitten?source=google` will be rewritten as `/news/template.shtml?news=hello-pink-kitten&source=google`)

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't appear to be working.  Perhaps it's because I have it in another directory?  Tried:

Comment: Disregard last message, it is because template.shtml with a query string is not omitted.  Trying to figure out a solution for this.

Comment: Disregard again. The template.shtml script was pulling another page into it within the directory which was causing the rewrite loop.  Thanks.